# How to use sp_execute_external_script to fetch USD Rate from an API and update a table?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, update, api

I have this code that gives this error

```
-- Set the API URL
SET @url = 'https://www.banxico.org.mx/SieAPIRest/service/v1/series/SF43718/dato/oportuno?token=734b37b3a5099a9d2d39d06478d47e359a9568cd6693116d95b710e6b8be0008';

-- Use built-in SQL Server functions to make HTTP request and obtain response
-- Requires SQL Server 2016 or later
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX);

-- Use sys.dm_exec_query_stats to enable SQL Server to execute external scripts
-- Indb is the database name
USE lndb;

EXEC sp_execute_external_script
@language = N'Python',
@script = N'
import requests

url = "https://www.banxico.org.mx/SieAPIRest/service/v1/series/SF43718/datos/oportuno?token=734b37b3a5099a9d2d39d06478d47e359a9568cd6693116d95b710e6b8be0008"
response = requests.get(url)
json_response = response.text
json_response',
@output_data_1_name = N'json',
@output_data_1 = @json OUTPUT;

-- Parse the JSON response using OPENJSON
DECLARE @usdRate DECIMAL(18, 6);

SELECT @usdRate = value
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.bmx.series[0].datos[0].dato') 
WITH (value DECIMAL(18, 6) '$');

-- Display the result
SELECT @usdRate AS USDExchangeRate;
```

> Msg 297, Level 16, State 101, Procedure sp_execute_external_script, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 0]
> The user does not have permission to perform this action.

Admin already gave me permission

[image: Admin already gave me permission]

Also what is sys.dm_exec_query_stats

Comment: Shouldn't it be `@output_data_1_name = N'json_response',`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should ask for this right:

```
USE <database_name>
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ANY EXTERNAL SCRIPT TO [UserName]
```